# Is it good practice to use traits only to reduce class complexity?

Tags: php, coding-style, traits

My base controller class has 2000+ lines. I know it's bad.
I'd like to split the class into small chunks to make it simpler.
May I use traits as "includes" to shorten the class?

For example, instead of

```
// Set instances in constructor
protected function loadInstances(){

  // Load Request helper
  $this->request = Container::getInstance('Request');

  // Load user model
  $this->user = Container::getInstance('User');

  // .... + 20 other classes
}
```

use the trait

```
trait ControllerInstances {
   // Define protected properties $request, $user etc
}
```

Comment: It only makes sense if your trait is going to be used in other places as well. If you use traits to "hide" the fact that your controller is that large, I would rather recommend a refactoring, since a controller should never need to be that big. Another solution would be to have a base class which you just extend.

Comment: In terms of good practice you need to go back and solve existing problem instead of hiding it. Your base controller is propably some god object and that usually happens when you look for abstractions in the wrong "dimension". Your controller should take `Request` and return a `Response` how many methods do you need to implement that? What your factory needs to know to decide which implementation to choose?

Comment: Magnus Eriksson: there are 2 nested classes - frontend/backend controller + router callback.

Comment: What is your definition of "frontend/backend controllers"? What is the difference between a controller and a router callback in your code? That is more or less the same thing. The router handles the URI, passes it to the correct controller/callback, the controller takes the request, calls the correct services/models (there should be no business logic in the controller) and just returns the response.

Comment: Backend controller intended for admin areas, ie site.com/admin, frontent controller - for public areas. Router callback is a method invoked per URL pattern. For example, login page: Controller - User, method - login. The User controller extends Frontend controller which is child of base controller

Comment: @ymakux, read something about "thin" ("skinny") controllers, it is considered good practice and can help you. Trait is just a syntax feature to reduce a code duplication, but not a right tool to "split" a classes.